# How do you find a circuit when you only have access to a wire in an open wall

Tags: electrical

I open a wall in a certain area with the intention to recess that area.
Of course there was wiring there, two wires of wich one I know where ig goes while the other I do not know.

How do I determine on which circuit/ breaker is this wire? Is there an induction based circuit breaker finder? The ones I am seeing are all based on a signal injector that is plugged into a power plug

Comment: The way I would do it in a home would be trial and error and a non contact voltage tester works 100% of the time if you think about it for a while.

Comment: I’ve found a tone tester to have enough oomph to induce the tone in adjacent wires. It might work through the nylon of an NM cable.

Comment: The problem with using the toner I’ve found is twofold. First you’ll need to shut off the main breaker to the panel and second because all the circuits are bonded together via the neutral bus on the panel, a strong tone signal can sometimes be heard in multiple cables / wires. It gets confusing fast.

Comment: Seeing you are going to move that cable anyway and will need to cut it.  Turn off main breaker cut and cap the wires.  Turn on main and see what does not work( make sure wife not watching her favourite TV show at the time).  Then can find the breaker after connecting the wires back together.  Have power off every time fingers and wires touch.  Then move and fix wires/cables in their final spot.

Comment: Do the non co tact Klein tools work at the breaker end only or also in the middle of the wire. I could try to attach that probe to power plugs in the arwa till it lights when the tester sits next to my wire